# In AS3, how can I check to see if mouse is inside a rectangle?

Tags: actionscript-3, onclick, mouse

In AS3, how can I check to see if mouse is inside a rectangle after the stage has been clicked in that area?

for example:

```
var rec:Rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 200, 50, 200);
```

And the onclick function would do:

```
if (mouseX <=rec.left && etc...
```

I've tried many methods, but have still come up empty. Any ideas?
(What I really wanted to do was make an event listener for the rectangle, but it kept throwing errors so I'm trying to figure out a way to do it with an if statement instead.)

This isn't pertinent that I know this, because I can just do this with flat numbers. I'm trying to learn more about rectangles and points. I figured this would work with a rectangle too, but nope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Rectangles` function `contains` which accepts 2 arguments `x` and `y`.
Like this:

```
var r:Rectangle = new Rectangle(50,200,50,200);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(r.contains(e.stageX,e.stageY))
    {
        trace("inside");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited your answer to use `stageX` and `stageY` properties, as they are aligned to stage, where is the listener. Also, there are `localX` and `localY` properties worth tracking in some situations. For example, if you want to check against a rectangle that's an area on a rotated display object, thus `e.localX` and `e.localY` will be the coordinates in that object's coordinate system, so you can use them without hassle.